# SQL Filtering by category

Tags: mysql, sql

`pro_id | Category
--------+---------
  25   | electronics
  27   | Electrical
  25   | household
  27   | electronics
  25    | industrial`

Above is my database table. I want to filter the results by category. If "electronics" is the selected category, the results should include product ids 25 and 27. This is easy. But I want to filter by multiple categories. For example if I select "electronics" and "household", the result should be only product id 25.

Comment: How do _you_ think you should be doing this? You may find you get a better quality of answer and that people are more willing to help you if you are able to demonstrate that you have [tried something for yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: If you were to guess at how to do it, what would your guess be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09028/7

Join your table to itself by pro_id, then filter by categories to select all product having both categories:

```
SELECT prod1.pro_id
FROM       prod AS prod1
INNER JOIN prod AS prod2 ON prod1.pro_id = prod2.pro_id
WHERE prod1.Category = 'electronics'
  AND prod2.Category = 'household';
```

Select all product having at least one category:

```
SELECT prod.pro_id
FROM  prod
WHERE prod.Category = 'electronics'
   OR prod.Category = 'household'
GROUP BY prod.pro_id;
```

Comment: why join ? why not `select * from prod Where prod.Category = 'electronics' OR prod.Category = 'household' ?`

Comment: It is required because otherwise pro_id=27 also would be selected, which has only one of the two required categories.

Comment: @ElVieejo: right - it's unclear whether the product must be part of both to satisfy the query.

Comment: @biziclop, sorry I retract my comment. Well done on understanding the question! Can you update your answer to include your analysis of the question and make it clearer?

Comment: I added both possible scenarios.

Comment: As I understood the question, he wanted ONLY pro_id = 25 if BOTH "electronics" and "household" was selected. This is obviously impossible, and will result only in 25, 27 ...unless I misunderstood?

Comment: Computer says `yes` in the sqlfiddle to me. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYhtEBfLMlo :)

Comment: Great biziclop... Both worked like a charm... Self inner join is perfect for my need. Thanks again...

Comment: Actually I like DRapp's solution better than my version :) Feel free to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only products that match BOTH criteria, you'll need a HAVING clause...

```
SELECT
      p.pro_id
   FROM       
      prod p
   where
      p.category in ('electronics', 'household')
   having
      count(*) = 2
```

The benefit of this is if you wanted 3 or more categories, all you have to do is add them to the "IN" clause and change the count to 3, 4 or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

No it shouldn't, because you have multiple IDs sharing the same Category name. The only way you're going to get what you want is to have another field that uniquely identifies each record, otherwise you have a mess on your hands with repeating data.

Comment: Let's say it is already `product_categories` table :) Of course distinct category names should go into a separate table.